# Geometric-arithmetic mean inequality applied to eigenvalues

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

I've applied the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality to the eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix $X$, so $det(X)^{1/n}≤tr(x)/n$.

Now I would like to show when equality holds. I already found out that equality holds if and only if X is a positive multiple of the identity matrix.

I've proofed already one direction (if X is a positive multiple of the identity matrix, then equality holds), but I am desperate with the second direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the other direction, you have to use the equality case in the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality which tells you that all values must be equal.

Denoting by $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ the (positive) eigenvalues of $X$, you have

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \right)^{1/n}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i,$$ and therefore $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_n=\lambda>0$.

Then you use the fact that since $X$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, $X$ can be written as $X=O^{-1}DO$ with $D=\lambda Id$ and $O$ an orthogonal matrix. Hence $X=\lambda Id$.